# "Block a website" script with vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, event-handling, userscript

I use this script to block access to a one or more websites with vanilla JavaScript. I find that it helps me avoid some addictive news websites that make me depressed. ([Credit to Marat Tanalin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47491200/domcontentloaded-sometimes-work-and-sometimes-doesnt-while-settimeout-usually-a) for helping me with the event handling.)

The script is aimed to be an all vanilla JavaScript imperative small script for personal usage, hence it's not modular (there isn't a HTML/CSS/JS file distribution on purpose).

To use the script please change `news_website_1.com` to a given news website you hate.

My personal main problem with the script is that it doesn't block websites right away or almost right away such as happens with [BlockSite Google Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/block-site-website-blocke/eiimnmioipafcokbfikbljfdeojpcgbh?hl=en):
For example, the script first loads a website, then about 5 seconds pass, then it gets blocked; for some reason, listening to the sooner `DOMContentLoaded` event [sometimes works and sometimes doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47491200/domcontentloaded-sometimes-work-and-sometimes-doesnt-while-settimeout-usually-a) and a reviewed version might show an improvement in that point.

**How would you revise this script?**

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @match        *
// ==/UserScript==

window.addEventListener('load', ()=> {
  let sitesToBlock = [
      'news_website_1.com'
  ];
  let regexToMatchTLD = /\..+/;
  let href = window.location.href;
  for (let i = 0; i < sitesToBlock.length; i++) {
      if (href.includes(sitesToBlock[i])) {
          let domain = sitesToBlock[i].replace(regexToMatchTLD, '');
          document.body.innerHTML =`
              <div style="direction: ltr; position: fixed; top: 0; z-index: 999999; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; background: red">
                <p style="position: relative; top: 40%; display: block; font-size: 66px; font-weight: bold; color: #fff; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center">
                  The website ${domain} successfully blocked !
                </p>
              </div>
        `;
      }
  }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main suggestion I have is to take the values from `sitesToBlock` and put them in the [`@match`](https://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40match) metadata key instead of detecting when to update the document content. There is an extensive guide about [match patterns here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns). With this approach there should not be any need to wait for the DOM to be loaded and check if the URL contains elements in `sitesToBlock`, though maybe that “news_website_1” loads slower than the one I tested with and that won’t work.

Other review points:

- **default to using `const`** instead of `let` when declaring variables unless re-assignment is mandatory. This helps avoid accidental re-assignment.
- **use [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loops** when possible- e.g. for iterating through `sitesToBlock` and there is no need for a counter variable (e.g. `i`) other than accessing the current element
- **`<script>` tags still executed** - those tags outside the body tag (e.g. in the [HTML `<head>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/head), or anywhere else) are still executed so it might make sense to remove those, otherwise the execution of a script could modify the document body after the user script has finished updating the document body, which likely would be undesirable.

Below is the script as I would update it. I know the `domain` might include `www` or another sub-domain if the site redirects to one - I modified the regex to look specifically for a final dot followed by anything that isn’t a dot and an [end of string anchor](https://javascript.info/regexp-anchors) (i.e. `$`).

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         page blocker
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  block pages
// @author       Sᴀᴍ Onᴇᴌᴀ
// @match        *://*.news_website_1.com/*
// @match        *://*.news_website_2.com/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(() => { //IIFE arrow function
    'use strict';

    const regexToMatchTLD = /\.[^.]+$/;
    const domain = location.hostname.replace(regexToMatchTLD, '');; 
    document.body.innerHTML =`
          <div style="direction: ltr; position: fixed; top: 0; z-index: 999999; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; background: red">
            <p style="position: relative; top: 40%; display: block; font-size: 66px; font-weight: bold; color: #fff; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center">
              The website ${domain} successfully blocked !
            </p>
          </div>
    `;
})();
```

Comment: Hello Sam; thanks for the review. Please share why you used `use strict`, I thought in ES6+ it is usually avoided on purpose (I don't know why exactly). Thanks,

Comment: @JohnDoea I tested my code in a greasemonkey script in opera and that was from the boilerplate. [the ES6 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-strict-mode-code) specifies that certain code will be run in strict mode- I believe the fifth bullet would apply: “_Function code is strict mode code if the associated ... **ArrowFunction** is contained in strict mode code or if the code that produces the value of the function’s [[ECMAScriptCode]] internal slot begins with a Directive Prologue that contains a Use Strict Directive._”

Comment: Hi, I suggested an edit that I think make it easier to read the answer - I also noted one section that wasn't clear to me - please feel free to reject or improve the edit...

Comment: It appears [the community did not accept your edit](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/122807) - likely because it was seen as changing the structure of my review too much. I have expanded the section about the script tags.

Comment: Thanks for everything Sam. One last thing please, what do you mean by `end of string anchor`? Thanks anyway !

Comment: I updated my answer to have more context about that end of string anchor in the regex

Comment: I tested the script, Two notes: In websites ending with `.co.uk` I get only `amazon.co` without the `uk`... Also, in some websites I get `www`; I humbly share that I personally never wanted to get that; if you want to edit no further - I totally understand. Thanks !

Comment: That was my attempt to improve the TLD removal pattern but feel free to not use the updated pattern. I should have clarified what should happen with various host names - e.g. with one dot, two dots, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can also explicitly run the script before the document loads by adding
`@run-at document-start` to your userscript.